# Wrong colors in some applications

Tags: colors, gpu-driver

Some apps on my Ubuntu 17.04 work with wrong colors (see screenshots).

For example:
Chrome (left) - bad; Firefox (right) - good.

[image]

GNOME Image Viewer (left) - bad; ImageMagick (right) - good.

[image]

Maybe these apps use different libs for image display, and one is buggy?
The video driver is NVIDIA 375.82.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofix.

The problem disappear after some of system updates...
Thanks to all involved...